# Why does my TextInputLayout's outLine box doesn't appear?

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

i want to wrap my edit text with outline box , so i am using TextInputLayout , but the outline box doesn't appear when i make my dialog full screen .

i detected that the problem is because i am making (homework dialog) full screen using this line of code :

```
   setStyle(STYLE_NO_TITLE,R.style.DialogHomework);
```

here is my homework dialog xml:

```
  <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
style="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/cancelHomework"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
    android:background="@drawable/circle_button"
    android:text="Cancel"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/addHomework" />

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout

    android:id="@+id/hw_dialog_title_layout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/hw_dialog_title_margin_start"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/hw_dialog_title_margin_start"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/hw_dialog_title_margin_top"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/hw_dialog_title_margin_end"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/hw_dialog_title_margin_end"
    app:boxBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
    app:boxBackgroundMode="outline"
    app:boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd="8dp"
    app:boxCornerRadiusBottomStart="8dp"
    app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="8dp"
    app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="8dp"
    app:boxStrokeColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    app:boxStrokeWidth="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/hw_dialog_material">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/hw_dialog_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:hint="@string/hw_dialog_title_hint"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/hw_dialog_material"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/hw_dialog_material_margin_start"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/hw_dialog_material_margin_start"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/hw_dialog_material_margin_top"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/hw_dialog_material_margin_end"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/hw_dialog_material_margin_end"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/hw_dialog_homework_layout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/hw_dialog_homework_margin_start"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/hw_dialog_homework_margin_start"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/hw_dialog_homework_margin_top"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/hw_dialog_homework_margin_end"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/hw_dialog_homework_margin_end"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/hw_dialog_homework_margin_bottom"
    android:gravity="top"
    app:boxBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
    app:boxBackgroundMode="outline"
    app:boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd="8dp"
    app:boxCornerRadiusBottomStart="8dp"
    app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="8dp"
    app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="8dp"
    app:boxStrokeColor="@color/primaryDark2"
    app:boxStrokeWidth="100dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/addHomework"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/hw_dialog_title_layout">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/hw_dialog_homework"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:hint="@string/homework_hint"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
<include

    android:id="@+id/toolBar"
    layout="@layout/toolbar"

    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/addHomework"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/circle_button"
    android:text="@string/add"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

my homework dialog code:

```
  public class newHomeWork extends DialogFragment {
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setStyle(STYLE_NO_TITLE,R.style.DialogHomework);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View dialog = inflater.inflate(R.layout.homework_dialog,container,false);
    Toolbar toolbar = dialog.findViewById(R.id.toolBar);
    toolbar.setTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
    TextView textView =toolbar.findViewById(R.id.homeworkDialogTitle);
    textView.setText("Add homework");
    Button add = dialog.findViewById(R.id.addHomework);
    Button cancel = dialog.findViewById(R.id.cancelHomework);
    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


        }
    });
    cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dismiss();
        }
    });


    return dialog;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Dialog dialog =  super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);


    return dialog;
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

}
}
```

my DialogHomeWork style :

```
 <style name="DialogHomework" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimary</item>


</style>
```

how it appears

[image]

how i want it:

[image]

Comment: Do you have any visual representation of how you want your `EditText` to appear? If yes then please provide the link or image.

Comment: @MayurGajra i edited it

Answer (score 4):

You can set the style for the TextInputLayout:

Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox

This should do the thing.

Simple example:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Test me">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: it wraps the layout with a outline box indeed , but the box isn't really adjusted , i think that because it overrides with its normal box , thanks anyway i appreciate your answer

Comment: do you know how to override textInputLayout style in dialog style ??

Comment: @moumenShobakey I think you can use <item name="editTextStyle">@style/EditTextDefault</item>

Comment: i tried :/ ,, never mind i'll just use backGroundMode = "filled" thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

Change your styles.xml Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar to Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar

Answer (score 0):

Just remove any command related to background color like this:

```
app:boxBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
```

Worked for me

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other suggestions, for a matter of distraction extending  from TextInputEditText to TextInputLayout with OutlinedBox, I've left a drawable shape as background and width to 0dp (before it was constrained):

Before :

```
     <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/nameEdit"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        app:hintEnabled="true"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/nameTextView">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/nameEditInput"

            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"

            android:hint="@string/profile_user_data_name_placeholder_textfield"
            android:inputType="textPersonName|textCapWords"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:paddingStart="10dp"
            android:textColorHint="@color/hint_color"
            android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/cursor_color"
            tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Fixed :

```
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/nameEdit"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        app:hintEnabled="true"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/nameTextView">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/nameEditInput"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:hint="@string/profile_user_data_name_placeholder_textfield"
            android:inputType="textPersonName|textCapWords"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:paddingStart="10dp"
            android:textColorHint="@color/hint_color"
            android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/cursor_color"
            tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```